# failing to work with the Random function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
'''val random1={Random()}'''
```

When i run the above kotlin code in intelij idea i get an error as
error: unresolved reference: Random
val random1={Random()}

Answer (score 0):

`Random(seed: Int)` is a pseudo-random number generator, it requires a seed (Int or Long) value to be passed as a parameter.

```
val random1 = Random(0)
```

To generate the random numbers use `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()`, `nextByte()` functions on the created generator.

```
val r1 = random1.nextInt()
val r2 = random1.nextFloat()
```

Read more about it here: [Kotlin Standard Library Random Number Generator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell the compiler which Random class you mean.

If you mean [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), then you'll need to specify the fully-qualified name:

```
val random1 = { java.util.Random() }
```

Or provide an [`import`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html#imports) for it:

```
import java.util.Random

val random1 = { Random() }
```

The same applies if you mean [`kotlin.random.Random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/) — though that's an abstract class and so you can't create an instance of it directly.

You should also be aware that your code doesn't create a Random object directly; it's a [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions), a function which will create and return a Random object when you call it.  If that's what you want to do, then fine!  But if not, then you'll probably want to remove the braces.